# Connect to an existing transaction on SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

Maybe this question is a little far-fetched but i'll give it a shot..
Can i connect to an ongoing transaction in some way?
The problem is that i have [C++ Program A] that does various operations on a database and then calls [C# Program B] that does more operation on the same database.
I want all those operations from both programs to run in a single transaction - thus allowing rollback for example.

Is it somehow possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Transactions are per-connection (in SQL Server, at least).

What you *can* do is to have a distributed transaction, which will be fully ACID.